# Start bash with a specific alias set

Tags: bash, alias

I need to start bash in such a way that a specific alias is set.  This specific alias would be

```
alias exit="echo Cannot exit"
```

This is important because I am running a program that can only run from one terminal, and I can run many of them, but only from that one terminal session.  Sometimes I accidentally kill it and then all the children die.  And this is a well-known modelling program, and I can't really change the way their license manager works.

Another option would be to pass a flag to this specific bash script, which would be tested in .bashrc and set the alias there.  But I don't know how to do this either.

Comment: See bash's option `--rcfile`.

Comment: ....  except...  my version gives me "Failed to parse arguments: Unknown option --rcfile".  I am running RedHat.  And yes, --rcfile does appear in the bash manpage.  Strange.

Comment: It works.  Now to implement devilspie to prevent the window decoration from appearing, then I can't kill the window.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/276847/running-gnome-terminal-with-no-window-border-on-startup-in-xubuntu-12-10

Comment: Sounds like you want to run this shell inside a screen or tmux window.

Answer (score 1):

```
screen -S mystupidprogram bash --rcfile ~/.bashrc-mystupidprogram
```

where `~/.bashrc-mystupidprogram` contains

```
. ~/.bashrc
setopt ignoreeof
enable -n exit
```

Running [screen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen) (or [tmux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmux) if you prefer) allows you to connect to that shell from anywhere with `screen -S mystupidprogram -rd` (screen calls this *reattaching*). To disconnect from a screen session but leave it running, which screen calls *detaching*, type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

Read the Bash manual under SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS. You could wrap your program in a shell script that uses the builtin `trap`.

Comment: Actually this program requires that I start it from the cl.  That is, if I want three such programs, I type the program with an ampersand three times.  When I want another one, I type it again.  The other three may or may not be running.  So wrapping my program in a shell is technically what I want, but they all have to start from the same shell, or the license manager won't service them.  I can't start three shells, in other words, so I have to start another interactive shell where I can spawn them as needed.  (A little VMS there...)